# How does the info entered in a force.com page get into the right place in Salesforce

Tags: workflow

I am volunteering doing Salesforce work for a food bank in CA. I am still new with respect to doing more complicated tasks.

I have some questions on VERY basic SF concepts.

I was given a sign up page and an email template to make a workflow rule. The sign up page sends out an email when one fills it out and submits it. I need to change that email template to something else but I need to figure out...

1) How does the data from the following page get into Salesforce and where does it go to (contacts)? `http://foodbankvolunteers.force.com/volunteers/GW_Volunteers__PersonalSiteJobListing?nMonthsToShow=2&jobid=a0Oi000000Fiolx`

2) How to determine (where to look?) which email template is being sent out when one clicks on the submit button (see above question)? (I am going to want to change the email template once I know where to do it.)

3) I want to send of an email once the data is in Salesforce, I have an email template that I was given. How to setup a workflow rule (on which object) such that it sends the email with the template that I want? (Contacts? Campaign?) If I do not see the fields that I want added to the email, does that mean I attached the workflow rule to the wrong object or are they really accessible but I just don't see them.

4) I did  "View Page Source" and see the following code. What does it mean?

```
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:SiteTemplate:j_id13:j_id14:frmSignUp" value="j_id0:SiteTemplate:j_id13:j_id14:frmSignUp" />
<span id="j_id0:SiteTemplate:j_id13:j_id14:frmSignUp:panelSignUp">
```

5) When I do "View Page Source" on a force.com page, the "action=" is sending data to a specific Salesforce page but on that page I do not see code that is processing the data that is sent to it. How does that page know to anything with the data that was sent to it?  (I.e. in PHP the data is sent to a variable `$_POST['somedata'];` How does Salesforce handle it?

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to add the page source output

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE sf123. You may want to try to get familiar with the Help button and resources on the SF web site where many of these things are explained in the free tutorials that get you started with the platform. YouTube also has many helpful video tutorials/webinars that have been uploaded by SF. @Girbot, the post just needed editing to format the code to make it visible.

Answer (score 3):

They're using the [Volunteers for Salesforce package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JBggEAG), but I believe that it's rather an older version from when the author, David Habib, worked for Groundwire, so you probably want to update the package. Check out [the documentation](http://djhconsulting.com/volunteers-for-salesforce/) for a better understanding of the pages and workflows:

Also, you can join the Volunteers for Salesforce group in the Power of Us Hub, the Salesforce Foundation's online community. David is active there and often answers specific questions. Log in with the credentials you have from the Food Bank's org: https://powerofus.force.com

Answer (score 0):

Most non-profits use a special add-on to the Enterprise Edition called the [Non-Profit Starter Pack](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/wiki) (NPSP) which has 5 parts to it, Contacts and Organizations, Affiliations, Relationships, Recurring Donations and Households. There's a recent update that takes it to version 3. You might want to install [Nonprofits 101](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B39t7EAB) from Cloud for Good,  if it's not already in your org. Its a free Salesforce Help Knowledge-base for Nonprofit and Educational Organizations meant to be used with the NPSP as a resource for training and reference to help users with the many features unique to the NPSP.

[The Power of Us Hub](http://www.salesforcefoundation.org/help/power-of-us-hub/) maintains the documentation for the NPSP. By clicking on these links, you'll find the [NPSP 3.0 Documentation](http://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Nonprofit-Starter-Pack-3-Documentation), the [NPSP Workbook](http://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Nonprofit-Starter-Pack-Workbook) and the link to [install/upgrade to NPSP 3](https://mrbelvedere.salesforcefoundation.org/mpinstaller/npsp). Be sure to read the [Release Notes](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/wiki/Release-Notes) if you're doing an update to 3.0 as there's preparation that needs to be done in your org in advance if you are.

Comment: Volunteers for Salesforce is a separate package from those in the Nonprofit Starter Pack, and will work with either NPSP 2 or NPSP 3. While the advice above is all generally useful for working with a nonprofit instance, it's not relevant to the specific question asked. Also - the AppEx NPSP packages are all still v2 - v3 has a [separate installer](https://mrbelvedere.salesforcefoundation.org/mpinstaller/npsp).